# Angular 2 Typescript Observable return first object result

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have the following post service with Observable

```
// Add a new order
addOrder(body: Object): Observable<Order[]> {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.authHttp.post(this.ordersUrl, bodyString, options)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

The server responds with the object it just created. Now i want to retrieve that one object and save it to the a variable in the component.

```
private myOrder: Order;

// Subscribe to observable
orderOperation.subscribe(
    orders => {
        // Emit list event
        EmitterService.get(this.listId).emit(orders);
        this.myOrder = ? 
    });
```

As the result is of type observable[] i am not able to assign to the object var. How can i get the contents of the observable into the object var myOrder?

Comment: If it just returns the one object (not an array) you can change the return type of your method to `Observable<Order>` instead of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the service returns a single object, just update your type like

```
addOrder(body: Object): Observable<Order> {
```

and it should work fine.

On subscribe part,

```
// Subscribe to observable
orderOperation.subscribe(
    order => {
        // Emit list event
        ...
        this.myOrder = order
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution .

```
  orderOperation.subscribe(
orders => {
    if(orders!=undefined){

         this.myorder=orders;
     }
});
```